# wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0) in controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to check whether the create action passes.

```
 describe "#create" do
  let!(:user){ create(:user) }
  let!(:post){ create_list(:post, 3, user: user) }
    context "authenticated user" do
      it "adds a new post" do   
        post_params = FactoryBot.attributes_for(:post)
        sign_in user  
        expect{ post :create, params: {post: post_params} }.to change(user.posts, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
```

but my error is

```
Failure/Error: expect{ post :create, params: {post: post_params} }.to change(user.posts, :count).by(1)

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)
```

posts_controller:

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if params[:images]
      if @post.save
        params[:images].each do |img|
          @post.photos.create(image: img)
        end
      else
      end
      redirect_to posts_path
      flash[:notice] = "success"
    else
      redirect_to posts_path
      flash[:alert] = "failure"
    end
  end
```

Comment: I changed 
`let!(:posts){ create_list(:post, 3, user: user) }`

Comment: my error is 
 `expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0`

Comment: Could you please show`FsctoryBot` for `post`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's most probably because the variable you are using, `let!(:post)`, is clashing with `post :create, params: {post: post_params}` (the `post` method).

Solution is to change `let!(:post)` to `let!(:posts)` since it is a list anyway.

Comment: I changed

`let!(:posts){ create_list(:post, 3, user: user) }
describe "#create" do
    context "authorized user" do
      it "add  a new post" do   
        post_params = FactoryBot.attributes_for(:post)
        sign_in user  
        expect{ post :create, params: {post: post_params} }.to change(user.posts, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end`

but my error is this.

` Failure/Error: expect{ post :create, params: {post: post_params} }.to change(user.posts, :count).by(1) expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0`

Comment: That means the post is not saving. Is it possible that `params[:images]` is nil? Your controller won't attempt to save the post in that case.

Comment: If that's not the problem, then perhaps the post is not valid. In your controller #create action, just after `@post = Post.new(post_params)`, temporarily add the following lines: `@post.validate` followed by `pp @post.errors.full_messages`. Then run your test and check the logs

Comment: @kodai this perfectly answers the original question. You had an `ArgumentError` and this answer explains why and how to overcome it. Fixing your tests for them to pass is completely out of scope of this question. Please accept this answer and ask another question if needed.

Comment: also you can get away without `let!(:post){ create_list(:post, 3, user: user) }` and just do `before { create_list(:post, 3, user: user) }` which is arguably better than `let!` if you don't use the defined `let!(:posts)` in the expectations.